# empathy-accounts replaced online accounts

Tags: empathy, online-accounts, telepathy

In ubuntu `empathy-accounts` replaced by "Online accounts". I have not my account in it. How to run `empathy-accounts` ?

Where i can find clear tutorial for porting `empathy-accounts` to `online-accounts` ?